# What event chains do different Way of Life focuses unlock?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

The expansion Way of Life expansion allows your character to take a focus such as hunting, seduction, rulership, etc.

What event chains / traits can I expect to unlock with the various focuses?

For instance, as a hunter I've noticed I have found cabins in the wood with err very lonely people and acquired a few lovers that way. Do all the focuses have similar random events that I can expect?

Comment: My experience with the business focus saw the birth of a construction guild, an expedition to a far away land to create a trade route and a chance to invest in a fledgling company. Massive profit all around. I believe most focuses open new event chains and a few give new diplomatic options. A full list would be a large undertaking, the dlc Promos claim over 100 new events total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CK2 Wiki](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Focus#Focuses) has a decent listing of Traits and effects of the various focuses:
[image]

It isn't totally complete as I've seen a few events while playing that are not currently listed, but it does give a decent idea of what to expect.